# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e07'

Tags: sql, asp-classic

Oké this one will probably be verry obvious but after 3 days looking at the same block of code to find the mistake i start loosing my mind over it.

Below 2 blocks of code. The 1st one works like a charm but the second one although i assume it's correctly coded keeps giving me issues.

```
SQL = "EXECUTE sp_AddEvent '" &_
chrEventName & "','" &_
chrEventManager & "','" &_
chrEventAssistant & "','" &_
txtEventDescr & "','" &_
intEventTypeID & "'," &_
intEventCatagoryID & "," &_
intIncomeModelID & "," &_
intEventStatusID & ",'" &_
dtEventStart & "','" &_
dtEventEnd & "','" &_
intMultiArea & "'," &_
intMultiLokation & "," &_
intMultiDay & ",'" &_
dtEventAdded & "','" &_
dtEventChanged & "','" &_
intEventLastChangedBy & "'"

'   Executing Insert statement.
SET rsAddEvent = someconnection.EXECUTE(SQL)
```

Now the second block which is driving me to complete madness by now.

```
SQL = "EXECUTE sp_AddLokation '" &_
chrLokationName & "','" &_
chrLokationStreet & "','" &_
chrLokationCity & "','" &_
chrLokationCountry & "','" &_
chrLokationSNumber & "','" &_
chrLocationZipcode & "','" &_
chrLokationPhone & "','" &_
chrLokationFax & "','" &_
chrLokationEmail & "','" &_
chrLokationWebsite & "','" &_
intLokationTypeID & "'," &_
intMultiArea & "," &_
intLokationStatusID & ",'" &_
dtLokationAdded & "','" &_
dtLokationChanged & "','" &_
intLastChangedBy & "'"

'   Executing Insert statement.
SET rsAddLokation = someconnection.EXECUTE(SQL)
```

the stored procedure which is called to insert the data is working fine so it has to be something at ASP level.

Does anyone has an suggestion to this weirdness before i start chewing on my keyboard?

In addition:
I either get an varchar to int conversion error or when fiddling with the ' in one of the last 3 int fields before dtlokationAdded i get an syntax error near (depending on the by fiddling affected field)

Comment: Are you sure there's no [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com) occuring? You're stuffing a LOT of values directly into a query string, and many of those look like they could have at least one `'` somewhere. Try dumping out the generated query string BEFORE you execute it

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?  Are you getting a conversion error?  I suspect the dates you are passing are not in an ANSI-standard format.

Comment: @ Marc B
This could be the case but then again. Why do even larger inserts in the app work fine and just this one keeps giving me headaches? tried your suggestion about dumping the generated query string before execution but it keeps bugging me with a syntax error in one of the last 3 fields or comes up with a varchar to int conversion error.

Comment: @ litleBobbyTables see my comment to Marc B

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all fields that starts with `int` are numeric (Except `intLastChangedBy`, which in the previous block is enclosed in quotes; if it is, remove that quote too):

```
SQL = "EXECUTE sp_AddLokation '" &_
chrLokationName & "','" &_
chrLokationStreet & "','" &_
chrLokationCity & "','" &_
chrLokationCountry & "','" &_
chrLokationSNumber & "','" &_
chrLocationZipcode & "','" &_
chrLokationPhone & "','" &_
chrLokationFax & "','" &_
chrLokationEmail & "','" &_
chrLokationWebsite & "'," &_
intLokationTypeID & "," &_
intMultiArea & "," &_
intLokationStatusID & ",'" &_
dtLokationAdded & "','" &_
dtLokationChanged & "','" &_
intLastChangedBy & "'"
```

Comment: Indeed all 'int' fields are numeric and i see where your suggestion goes and tried that already without any result.

Comment: @Normanius .. and you must have seen this ..  http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/why-do-i-get-80040e57/80040e07-errors.html

Comment: Seen it. But I'm not having issues with data-types or field lengths that are out of range. all my 'int' fields are either switch fields which receive 1 or 0. Or they contain an ID value from some other table. "maybe it's far fetched but could it be the order in which i send the data?? this differs from the order used by the stored procedure"

Comment: @Normanius and the text field lengths are also ok ? the order will matter, i think. Unless you are binding the sp parameters using command.parameters.add where you specify the 'name' of the parameter. Here, the order will matter.

Comment: Text field lengths are ok and cannot be exceeded by user input cause at form level it's length limited down 4 chars from the max i have set at column level. I changed the order and right now instead of an varchar to int conversion error I receive a varchar to date conversion error.

Comment: @Normanius so now you could change the order of the parameters to match that in the sp definition and check

Answer (score 0):

```
intLokationTypeID & "'," &_
```

Well, I noticed here you have a set of quotation marks but only one apostraphe... that could be causing an error?  Or, wait, I think I see where you closed it. (couple lines down, sorry!)

Comment: Yup due to my messing around with quotation and apostrophes the original ordering of the fields has become a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks all for trying to help me out here!

It seems my issue is resolved.
It must be code-midgets who payed me a visit last night. Other than that i can't explain what just happened. Cause when i left the project yesterday it sure as hell wasn't working at all.